# Regarding Canada Sponsor eligibility for Parents and Grandparents

Tags: canada

Under the Canadian Parents and Grandparents sponsorship program, one of the eligibility requirements for the sponsor is that "they must be earning above a certain threshold salary for 3 tax years before applying to sponsor under the program." See [this.](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1445&top=14)

I wanted to know whether the prospective sponsor is required to show sufficient earning **in Canada necessarily**? Would it suffice to show that the sponsor has been earning above the threshold since 1 year in Canada and since the 2 years before that in the US?

My question is, that if I am earning above the threshold in the US for 2 years now (or take 1 year), can I meet the requirement by working and earning above that threshold in Canada for 1 year (or 2 year respectively?)

Kindest regards.

Answer (score 1):

The [website](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1445&top=14) you link to says (in Footnote 1):

> To **prove you meet the income requirement,** you must provide your **Notice of Assessment** from the Canada Revenue Agency (CRA) for the **last 3 taxation years** before you apply.

This wording suggests they don't care about where you earned the money, as long as you filed a tax return in Canada for the last three years.